# Change the location of an object programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, runtime

I've tried the following code:

```
 this.balancePanel.Location.X = this.optionsPanel.Location.X;
```

to change the location of a panel that I made in design mode while the program is running but it returns an error:

> Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable.

So how can I do it?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The `Location` property has type `Point` which is a struct.

Instead of trying to modify the existing `Point`, try assigning a new `Point` object:

```
 this.balancePanel.Location = new Point(
     this.optionsPanel.Location.X,
     this.balancePanel.Location.Y
 );
```

Answer (score 17):

Location is a struct. If there aren't any convenience members, you'll need to reassign the entire Location:

```
this.balancePanel.Location = new Point(
    this.optionsPanel.Location.X,
    this.balancePanel.Location.Y);
```

Most structs are also immutable, but in the rare (and confusing) case that it is mutable, you can also copy-out, edit, copy-in;

```
var loc = this.balancePanel.Location;
loc.X = this.optionsPanel.Location.X;
this.balancePanel.Location = loc;
```

Although I don't recommend the above, since structs should ideally be immutable.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that structs should ideally be immutable. Strangely though... `public int X { get; set; }` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.x.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Use either:

```
balancePanel.Left = optionsPanel.Location.X;
```

or

```
balancePanel.Location = new Point(optionsPanel.Location.X, balancePanel.Location.Y);
```

See the [documentation of Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.location):

> Because the Point class is a value type (Structure in Visual Basic,
>   struct in Visual C#), it is returned by value, meaning accessing the
>   property returns a copy of the upper-left point of the control. So,
>   adjusting the X or Y properties of the Point returned from this
>   property will not affect the Left, Right, Top, or Bottom property
>   values of the control. To adjust these properties set each property
>   value individually, or set the Location property with a new Point.

Answer (score 5):

If somehow balancePanel won't work, you could use this:

```
this.Location = new Point(127, 283);
```

or

```
anotherObject.Location = new Point(127, 283);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the whole point to location

```
var point = new Point(50, 100);
this.balancePanel.Location = point;
```

Answer (score 0):

When the parent panel has locked property set to true, we could not change the location property and the location property will act like read only by that time.