# Move a button's location after it is already drawn

Tags: c#, winforms

On my C# Winform (VS 2010 / C# / .Net 3.5), I have created a button in the designer.  I want to move and resize that button to a different location based on a user's setting upon start-up of that form.

In my form's load event, I have the following code to move and resize the button:

```
btnShare.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 496);
btnShare.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(4);
btnShare.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(408, 126);
```

All of the code to create the button is  *.designer.cs file for this particular form.

The problem is this:  When the form loads, I can see the button in it's new location based on the 3 lines of code above.  But then when the form is done loading and going through all it's events, the button goes back to it's original location which is in the *.designer.cs InitalizeComponent() method.

I do not want to take the code out of the *.designer.cs file and put it only into the form's .cs file because I still want to be able to see the button in the designer when I work on the design of the form.

I just want to move and resize the button if the user has that option toggled upon loading of the form.

How can I do this since .Net seems to draw the buttons on my form after the load event has processed thus moving the button back to it's original spot?

Comment: `InitalizeComponent` should only be getting called from your constructor which gets/should get called well ahead of the Load event. I would put a breakpoint at the beginning of InitalizeComponent to see where it's getting called from.

Comment: In which event is the move and resize code happens in ?

Comment: @Paul: InitalizeComponent is getting called way before the load event, but it seems like the buttons do not actually pop up until all the events are done.  When my form loads, I can see the same button in two different spots (the original location in designer.cs and the new location that I have in the load event).  But as soon as the form loads, the button that is in the second location disappears, and I am only left with the original button that is created in designer.cs.  It's as if the code in designer.cs that sizes/locations the button is overriding the code that I have in the load event.

Comment: Set a break point in your designer and then in your load event ... I bet for some reason your load event is firing before the designer code is being run.

Comment: @Micah:  I set a break point and the InitializeComponent() (designer code) is being called as soon as my form starts up.  Then the events are being called afterwards (load, resize, etc).  But for some reason as soon as the form is done loading, the button goes back to it's original location and size.

Comment: @fraXis Your desired functionality is common and works fine. Something else is happening (anchor, other logic, host controls). Work in a test project, or comment-out junk until you find it.

Comment: Can you provide us with a small code sample that reproduces?

Comment: There's a simple explanation for this, but that doesn't really matter.  What you are doing, using hard-coded location and size in the Load event is fundamentally wrong.  You need to do that *before* the Load event runs to ensure that the form's AutoScaleMode property can do its job.  Move the code to the constructor, after the InitializeComponent() call.

Comment: I tried it after the InitializeComponent() call and it had no effect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Change the location of an object programatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369999/c-sharp-change-the-location-of-an-object-programatically)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's some code I just spiked together.  and It works for me.

This is a SSCCE, a Simple, Self-Contained Correct Example.  Very useful when asking questions on SO.

*Since I don't know what your specific problem is, the *Correct*, part might not be accurate in this case

Try and make a copy of this project, and see if you experience the same issue.  If you don't than We really can't help you that much without getting more information about your project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            button1.Location = new Point(40, 40);
        }
    }
}
```