# C# "new" command

Tags: c#, location, point

I got a question, when I try to relocate a panel e.g. named `pPan`, I got 2 different ways to do that:

Inside a click event of a button I write

```
pPan.Location = new Point (
  pPan.Location.X +10 , pPan.Location.Y );
```

Or I can write:

```
pPan.Location.X += 10;
```

So what is the difference here? Why do I create this `new Point`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Location property has type Point which is a struct. you may receive error like

> Cannot modify the return value of
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Location' because it is not a variable

when you set X, Y values of it.

but you can asign new Point object:

```
pPan.Location = new Point (
  pPan.Location.X +10 , pPan.Location.Y );
```

**[`Control.Location` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx)**

> Because the Point class is a value type (Structure in Visual Basic,
>   struct in Visual C#), it is returned by value, meaning accessing the
>   property returns a copy of the upper-left point of the control. So,
>   adjusting the X or Y properties of the Point returned from this
>   property will not affect the Left, Right, Top, or Bottom property
>   values of the control. To adjust these properties set each property
>   value individually, or set the Location property with a new Point. If
>   the Control is a Form, the Location property value represents the
>   upper-left corner of the Form in screen coordinates.

Related SO Question : [C# Change the location of an object programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369999/c-sharp-change-the-location-of-an-object-programatically)

Answer (score 2):

If `Point` is a `struct`, you must use first one, because when you call the property, it returns a copy of the `Location`, and you try to modify the copy.

Comment: However, if it was a `struct`, it should not have a property setter to avoid this confusion (immutable type)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that in first way you allocate new memory for Point object. second way you are only change the property of existing object.

It is a good practice to operate existing objects as much as possible. So i suggest you use the second way to change location.