# How can I set programmatically the location of the control on the panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, panel

On my WinForms application I allow user to add and change location of the controls on a panel.Previously I wrote my code in WPF and I used canvas property SetTop:

```
canvas1.SetTop(img, position_x);
canvas11.SetLeft(button, position_y);
```

where I could pass control (image or button) and location X (or Y) in pixels.

How can I achieve this in WinForms where the background is a panel?

Comment: `button.Location = new Point(0, 0);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Change the location of an object programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369999/c-sharp-change-the-location-of-an-object-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks,@LarsTech