# How to do I scroll to side with buttons in WinForms in Visual Studio C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I know how to scroll vertically/horizontally with buttons but I am not able to figure out how to scroll towards Left/Right.

What I want is that when I click the button `LeftScrlBtn` I should scroll to left and when I click the `RightScrlBtn` I should scroll to right.

My FlowLayoutPanel's `AutoScroll` property is set to `false` because I don't want the scroll bar, only the buttons.

### Edit

To make this post more understandable, here is the code:

```
using System;
using [...];

//rest of the code

private void LeftScrlBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Code to scroll to Left
}

private void RightScrlBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Code to scroll to Right
}

//I want to know the code to scroll left and the code to scroll right
```

### Note

I wanted to tell that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369999/change-the-location-of-an-object-programmatically) didn't help me.

Comment: Please add the code so far so we understand what you try to do..

Comment: Scrolling only works when the object is larger than the view.  A control has four properties 1) Top 2) Left 3) Height 4) Width.  So when you scroll you are using the four properties to insert a portion of the object into a view.

Comment: @NoNAME, Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to scroll the FlowLayoutPanel by using the button.

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // need to disable AutoScroll, otherwise disabling the horizontal scrollbar doesn't work
            flowLayoutPanel.AutoScroll = false;

           // disable horizontal scrollbar
          flowLayoutPanel.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = false;


        }
        public int scrollValue = 0;
        public int ScrollValue
        {
            get
            {


                return scrollValue;
            }
            set
            {
                scrollValue = value;

                if (scrollValue < flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum)
                {
                    scrollValue = flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Minimum;
                }
                if (scrollValue > flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum)
                {
                    scrollValue = flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
                }

                flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.Value = scrollValue;
                flowLayoutPanel1.PerformLayout();

            }
        }
        private void btnleft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollValue -= flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;

        }

        private void btnright_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScrollValue += flowLayoutPanel1.HorizontalScroll.LargeChange;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Button() { Width = 67, Height = flowLayoutPanel1.Height});
        }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You could place all your controls in a panel that is transparent and is overflowing over the form's bounds (eg. if form is 500px in width and 600px in height you can make the panel be wider than the form and place controls in there). Leave some space under the panel and add your buttons there.

To the LeftScrlBtn_Click block of code add the following: `this.panel1.Left--;`

Add this to the RightScrlBtn_Click: `this.panel1.Left++;`

Of course, you can change the incremention value of the panels so it would scroll faster. Just replace ++ with +=5 or -- with -=5 to scroll 5 pixels on click, per example.

Here is a code sample I did (goes into Form1.cs) :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace StackOfAnswer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
      public Form1()
      {
        InitializeComponent();
      }
      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        //Scrolling left
        this.panel1.Left--;
      }
      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        //Scrolling right
        this.panel1.Left++;
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the code that goes into Form1.Designer.cs :

```
namespace StackOfAnswer
{
   partial class Form1
   {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(-3, -1);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(904, 422);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 427);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "scroll left";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(713, 427);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button2.Text = "scroll right";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(24, 136);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1561, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = " example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example example ";
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
}
}
```

This should do it.

Comment: I was not able to understand the code which is written before the code. Could you please Edit your answer a little?

Comment: I've edited the answer a little, hope it helps. Sorry again for the bad formatting, I'm new. The code should run fine in VS2019.

Comment: @mihaievo, Is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT your answer is a great alternative too! It works. Maybe OP forgot to mark one as answer ¯\_(ツ)_/¯